# Java - removing an element in list while iterating it with a for index loop

Tags: java

I know that removing an element from a list while iterating it is not recommended.
You better use iterator.remove(), java streams, or copy the remove to an external list.

But this simple code just works:

```
 static List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
 ...
 private static void removeForI() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        if (i == 3) {
            list.remove(i);
            continue;
        }
        System.out.println(i);
    }
 }
```

Is it safe to use it?

Comment: Yes, *assuming* the list has at least 4 elements to start with.

Comment: Yes, it's fine if you're not using an iterator. Just make sure your index is where you want it to be after removing.

Comment: It'll skip the element that starts at index 4.

Comment: As long as you have more than 3 elements in the list to start with, it should be fine.

Comment: @LouisWasserman It's a trick question. It's just printing `i`, not the element at index `i`. Result is that 4th element is removed from list, and that code prints `0 1 2 4 5 6 7 8 9`, skipping the number `3`, but not skipping any element.

Comment: That example is too forced, and fails to be useful because it doesn't use the list except for removing. If you wanted to remove the index `3` specifically then you wouldn't need a for. And if you use the list in the `for` loop you will be out of bounds after removing the element

Comment: why do not make another list? let say `toRemove`, add there elements that must be remeved and after loop make `'list.removeAll(toRemove)`.  it is 100% safe for any cases, index, iterator... who cares?

Comment: Well, if you know what you do, you can definitely do it like you have shown. It's just that its often a **source for potential bugs** because people tend to forget that they need to take care if they do that. That's why the `Iterator` implementation throws a `ConcurrentModifcationException` if you iterate over it and modify the underlying collection.

Answer (score 3):

You need to think about how `list.remove(index)` works.
When `remove(idx)` gets called, the element at `idx` index gets deleted and all the next elements gets shifted to left. 
So, suppose you have a list containing 2, 3, 3, 4, 5. Now you want to remove all the 3s from this list. But if you use your current approach, it will remove only the first occurrence of 3. Because after removing 1st occurrence of 3 which is at position 1 your contents will get shifted to left and will be like this 2, 3, 4, 5. But now your for loop will increment the current index  to 2 which contains 4 and not 3. 
That is why it is not advised to remove items while iterating, Because index of items gets changed after each removal.

Edit: Also if you are using a constant value in loop break condition like in above example `i<10;` you might get `ArrayIndexOutOfBounds` exception.

Comment: Last edit is exactly right. @ScalaNooB Just try `System.out.println(list.get(i));` instead of `System.out.println(i);` inside your loop.

Answer (score 0):

Even though it works under the condition people have pointed out, I would only use it temporarily and change it to:

```
private static void removeForI() {
    list.remove(3);
    list.foreach(System.out::println);
}
```

There is no need to check if i==3, simply remove it before the for loop.

Comment: perhaps condition is not that simple to remove only 3-rd element. Otherwise in the example there is no reason to keep looping when 3-rd element removed... there can be just `break;` instead of `continue;`

Comment: I agree on the condition. But the continue makes sure all the following elements are printed as well, which a break couldn't do. Nevertheless, I would never try to solve this like ScalaNooB in the first way.

Comment: h-m-m... example does not print following elements. :-) it prints indexes - `System.out.println(i);` if print following elements code is broken.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like that loop will be having a different conditional later on as otherwise you can simply do as JoschJava stated.

However if you truly want to iterate through all of your elements and remove a specific one during the loop, you may want to shift the index backwards afterwards. If that is the case, I would add this at the end of your conditional body:

`i -= 1;`

Answer (score 0):

It isn't safe at all. When you know you might temper the list during iteration, convert your **list object** into **Iterator object** then use its methods : *hasNext, next, remove...*